How to extract code and code verifier which needs to be passed as a payload in token API
Our application is using O-Auth2 protocol for authentication. Once i login to the system i see the token API which is generating the Access Token which is utilized for further APIs. Now this API has a payload with code and code verifier information. Both of these code and code verifier values are dynamic. Problem is i don't see any previous APIs which are generating these two values. So i am not sure how to extract the values and pass on to this Token API's payload. Already talked to BE guy and they are saying these values are getting generated through some Keytool package. So i am stuck in making these values dynamic and to run token API from JMeter. Any elaborate explanation will be really appreciated.

Code verifier is something you need to generate, example code can be found at i.e. Create code verifier page, translated into JMeter's JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language it would be something like:
import java.security.SecureRandom;

SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
byte[] code = new byte[32];
sr.nextBytes(code);
String verifier = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(code);

log.info('code_verifier: ' + verifier)

vars.put('verifier', verifier)

Then refer generated value as ${verifier} where required.
With regards to "code" - this is something you need to extract from the response

Thanks a lot for that...But i am still not able to find any other API which is producing the code......Actually there are couple of APIs which had the code as request header(the code was present as a referer). But the problem is that the header information is changing for these APIs. And the code is not present as a request header information next time when i logged in. In fact when i was parsing this API through JMeter it was not utilizing the referer as a header information at all. So what is the reason that the header information is changing for specific APIs each time the API is called.
